# Save the users location in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, geolocation

My problem is to search and display all the register users nearby some meter. After googling a lot without find a good solution I start writing very simple code (I use mdg:geolocation).

main.js

```
// in the client side
Template.localPosition.helpers({
    'getLocalPosition': function(){
        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
        if( currentUserId ) { 
            var localPos = Geolocation.latLng();
            return "LAT:" + localPos.lat + " LNG:" + localPos.lng;
        }
    }
});
```

In main.html I display a 'localPosition' template with `{{getLocalPosition}}` call. It work, but in the console panel I have:

> Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

Why is this?

Comment: Can you please show the rest of the body html code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ciessesse/4Lrwjtam/

Comment: I have rolled back the solution edit to your question, since we want to preserve questions here for future readers. Please add your answer to below in an answer box, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the var `localPos` is `null`, you should have an if statement to check if localPos has a readable value:

```
Template.localPosition.helpers({
    'getLocalPosition': function(){
        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
        if( currentUserId ) { 
            var localPos = Geolocation.latLng();
            if(localPos) {
              return "LAT:" + localPos.lat + " LNG:" + localPos.lng;
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In the web page i see the lat and lng values and whit a alert(localPos.lat) it show correct value

Comment: Because at first when your app is rendered, the data may not be ready yet it takes time for server to send data to client. Therefore your `localPos` may be `null` at first but later it has the correct value.

Comment: ty @Khang there is a solution to wait server time?

Comment: @user6720641 - Did you try the if condition around locationPos as khang suggested?

Comment: If you use `.subscribe` to get data, you could use [`handle.ready()`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe) to check if the data is ready, `handle` is the returned value when your call `.subscribe`

Comment: YES it work with the if! ty all! Second question(s) where to save the local position? in the user collection? in a separate collection? How to intercept the login event?

Comment: To intercept login event you could use: [onLogin](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin) or [validateLoginAttemp](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-validateLoginAttempt). About where to store the location data, you should create another question with information about your logic it will be easier to answer

Comment: ty all, i'll write new question